# Change title bar color of some apps

Tags: themes, title-bar

is it possible to change the title bar of some apps to dark specifically sublime text 3? and how? I tried using [gtk-theme-variant-switcher](https://github.com/oktayacikalin/gtk-theme-variant-switcher) but it doesn't work with the latest EOS. There's also an [extension](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/GTKDarkThemeVariantSetter) for sublime text 3 but looks like it was archived a long time ago. Thanks.